# Переопределение метода Math.random()

Tags: javascript

Меня не совсем устраивает стандартный `Math.random()` и я хотел бы переопределить его, написав свою функцию. Возможно ли это?

Само собой вы скажите: "Сделайте функцию `MathRandom`!", тут все понятно, я не спорю, но интересен именно момент с переопределением.

В JS не так давно, пробовал через prototype, но увы, без результата.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Math.random = function(){alert(1);}
Math.random() //выведет алерт
```

И не нужно с прототипом ничего делать 
Если в переопределённой функции нужно использовать метод поумолчанию то сохраните на него ссылку перед затиранием.

```
var oldRandom = Math.random;
Math.random = function(){
    //pre logic
    oldRandom.call(this); //вызов старого рандома
    //post logic
}
```

Не знаю точно нужно ли применять контекст выполнения, но лучше перестраховаться, вдруг там вызовы других методов

Answer (score 0):

Собственно сделал следующим образом, все работает, спасибо!

```
    OldRandom = Math.random;
    Math.random = function( Min, Max )
    {
        if( Max )
            if( typeof( Min ) == "number" && typeof( Max ) == "number" )
                return Math.floor( OldRandom() * ( Max - Min + 1 ) ) + Min;
            else
                return false;
        else
            if( typeof( Min ) == "number" )
                return Math.floor( OldRandom() * ( Min - 1 + 1 ) ) + 1;
            else
                return false;
    }
```

Comment: Жуть... Зачем проверки на тип? `Min-1+1` - ну как же это самому посчитать? И `return false`. И это не говоря про стиль.

Comment: Да, спасибо. На счет -1, 1 убрал, не придал нужное значение.